# MySql could not connect to Sailsjs on sails lift

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I have just started coding in sailsjs, and i am trying to connect it to a Mysql database. I have installed "sails-mysql". I have also created the database using the mysql commands. These are the contents of my 'config' files. I
connections.js

```
  mysql: {
adapter: 'sails-mysql',
host: '127.0.0.1',
port: 27017,
user: '', //optional
password: '', //optional
database: 'new_db',
schema: true //optional
}
```

models.js

```
module.exports.models = {
connection: 'mysql',
migrate: 'alter'
};
```

I get this error on 'sails lift'.

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
at afterwards 
(/home/kshd97/Desktop/projects2/sails/actvity/node_modules/sails-
mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:72:13)
at /home/kshd97/Desktop/projects2/sails/actvity/node_modules/sails-
mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
at Handshake.onConnect 
(/home/kshd97/Desktop/projects2/sails/actvity/node_modules/sails-
mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:54:9)
at Handshake.Sequence.end 
(/home/kshd97/Desktop/projects2/sails/actvity/node_modules/sails-
mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
at /home/kshd97/Desktop/projects2/sails/actvity/node_modules/sails-
mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:399:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at /home/kshd97/Desktop/projects2/sails/actvity/node_modules/sails-
mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:13
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

What could be the cause of this error and how do i resolve it?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I faced a similar issue, removed the port number key value pair; letting it run on the default port and it worked. Seems like an issue with the port number.

Comment: Error persists..

Answer (score 0):

you should change mysql port to `3306` as `27017` it's for mongodb, add username and password of mysql connection and make sure you are passing the correct credentials by test it on mysql shell :-

```
mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -d DBNAME
```

here is an example of mysql-config how it looks like

```
module.exports.connections = {
  mysql: {
    module    : 'sails-mysql',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 3306,
    user      : 'username',
    password  : 'password',
    database  : 'MySQL Database Name'

    // OR (explicit sets take precedence) 
    module    : 'sails-mysql',
    url       : 'mysql2://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASENAME'

    // Optional 
    charset   : 'utf8',
    collation : 'utf8_swedish_ci'
  }
};
```